# In tensorflow, how to optimize the variables in judgement?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just want to ask a simple question that has bothered me for a few days. I want to optimize some variables in the judgement with tensorflow. For example:

```
if -k < X < k
    do something
else
    do something
```

I want to find the best `k` with tensorflow. But with traditional neutral network, it just told me that `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients.` since there is no variable `k` in `do something`, so the network can't solve the gradient. Can anyone give me some advice? Thank you!

Actually I want to build a sensor noise model. Considering a series of sensor output data and a reference data. The model is as follows:

```
if reference - k * sigma < sensor output < reference + k * sigma
     output = sensor output
else 
    output = reference
```

If `k` is to big, the error between sensor output and reference data would be too big; If 'k' is too small, output data may not show the actual situation of the sensor. 
However, the variable `k` is in the judgement, which means that tensorflow can't solve its gradient. So I want to know how to handle this situation

Comment: Please explain your question with more detail of question, code and input/output examples.

Comment: Start by posting code which doesn't throw SyntaxError and fulfills minimum verifyable example criteria.